# Does anyone know how to write this symbol in latex

Tags: circles

[image: I with a little circle on it]

I can't figure out how to type this in latex. It's a I with a little circle on the middle.

Comment: ​‍​‍​‍​‍​Φ​​​​​​​‍​‍​‍​‍​‍​

Comment: Is special case of [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara). DeTeXify should work

Comment: \[\Phi\] or $\Phi$ (\usepackage{amsmath} in the preabule).

Comment: With the TeXnicCenter editor you can look up `Math->Greek Capital Letters` in the menu.